# Intuition behind negative radians in an interval

Tags: trigonometry, intuition

Say a function's domain is $[−\pi,\pi]$. How should I interpret this interval? 
It starts from where? To where? In what direction?

Comment: This question is eerily similar to [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711469/how-to-read-negative-radians-in-the-interval?rq=1)

Comment: The fact that the endpoints of the interval map into the same point in Cartesian coordinates may be causing some confusion, so in that respect, this question may be not an exact duplicate of the one mentioned in KoA's comment.